# Apache Cordova and Phone Gap

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm Newbie to phone gap, I've hear that the phone gap used to develop by one code and implement for different devices such as Android,ios,etc. The way i'm understanding is correct? if correct means Cord-ova allow a mobile app developer to access native device function such as the camera  from JavaScript using different API'S. If i want to implement for both Android and IOS how can i use separate IOS API'S and android API'S in single project. Still i didn't get the fundamentals for phonegap

Comment: check this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've heard that the phone gap used to implement one code and implement for Android,ios,etc. The way i'm understanding is correct?**

PhoneGap is actually a wrapper that allows your application written using web technologies like HTML5, CSS, Javascript to deploy on different platforms like iOS and Android. Unlike platform-specific native applications, you write your code using standard web technologies and PhoneGap takes care of deploying it to different platforms. So, YES it is "Code once - Deploy in many". However, there are some limitations in which you cannot compete with native applications.

**PhoneGap allow a mobile app developer to access native device function**

Yes, you can access most of native functionality through PhoneGap. You can refer the API Reference in this [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/) .

**If i want to implement for both Android and IOS how can i use separate IOS API'S and android API'S in single project.**

You will need to read their  [Platform Guidelines](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides)  for a better clarity. They do have certain steps/guidelines for each platform. However, this is relatively easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks man, if it possible na, pls share some project which are deployed on both android and IOS...

Comment: One deployed project you can find on Android playstore is "Arcot panchangam". This is available in Appstore as well. Was developed using phoneGap.

Comment: No i don't want application.. i need some free project to learn how they are worked.. That's all

Comment: Nanbaa.. It is really hard to share a project.. But aana, you can go through the examples given the phonegap. Just try with simple example.. That will help you get started.. Adhuvey podhum..

Comment: Mikka Nandri..i asked some Git hub links that's all buddy.. Anyway thanks for your valuable information

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is exactly what you said: it provides a set of native APIs accessible from your Javascript code.

As of now (used to be different in previous versions), you have a single Phonegap project that is built for the different platforms you want to target. This build process can be done locally in your machine if you have all the specific platform toolchain, or remotely using the Phonegap Build service.

Phonegap command line tools create a sub-project for each of the targeted platforms, that you may import from your platform-specific IDEs (Eclipse, XCode) if you like to, but it is not required unless you want to somehow tweak the native code.

Hope you got it clearer.